# Access usbtmc without /dev/usbtmcX

Tags: usb, devices

I'd like do:

echo 'cmd' >> /dev/usbtmc0

but instead of referencing /dev/usbtmc0, I'd like to reference something that has the usb product-id and vendor-id.

e.g. echo 'cmd' >> /dev/0x1234:0x5678
obviously ^ doesn't work.

Is there any way to find out where /dev/usbtmc0 actually points to?  I can see it's not a symlink.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The command you show would attempt to write the sting `cmd` directly onto the USB device. Not a very good idea. Please [edit] your question and explain what your objective is.

Comment: I'd just like to know which usb product-id and vendor-id corresponds to a given USBTMC number in /dev

Comment: Then please ***[edit]*** your question so it asks what you need. Your `echo cmd` is very misleading since it looks like you are trying to write data directly onto the device. Are you just looking for `lsusb`? For one of the `/dev/disk/by-*` directories? Please edit and clarify.